# How to get method name in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

**main.ts**

```js
class C {
  m() {}
}
const c = new C()
console.log(c.m.name)
```

I have written a simple script to get the name of the method in Typescript. However, when I compile the code and open it in the web browser I got `undefined` as the output. Is there any way to get the method name in the compiled script file?
**Edit:** Also worth noting that I am writing TypeScript in *Node.js*.

Comment: I am using TypeScript `4.0.5`. Your code works for me. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQjGBsEMGduBhYBvAUCdwC2AKAlMgXzRCPVAHsA7aAF2FGAF5hKBTAdwT2PqunPCsAdOHIBzbKCGYhlSJla4gA)

Comment: This smells more of browser differences than any problem with TypeScript.

Comment: Now I tried it on the playground too. It really works but it seems there is a problem in my local workspace. Maybe because I am developing for Node?

Comment: Judging based off of the compatability graph on Mozilla Developer Network it seems that `Function.name` is locked behind the `--harmony` flag for Node 6.x.x+ https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name#browser_compatibility

Comment: TypeScript is not involved. Everything happens at runtime, it is JavaScript only.

Comment: It works fine with the latest versions of Node.js 8, 10 and 12.

Answer (score 0):

Try to run this in typescript playground will run fine

```
class C {
   m() {
      console.log('dsad');
  }
}
const c = new C()
console.log(c.m.name);
```

Comment: This runs the method and does not answer the question.

Comment: Now can try getting the name

Comment: How does it answer the question now?

Comment: How to get method name in TypeScript? is giving undefined value can try this code in typescript